# Automate migration of big project to Flutter Bloc 8.0 & above

Tags: flutter, dart, migration, bloc

I have a huge project which uses `flutter_bloc: ^7.0.`

-> I'd like to migrate it with the newest `flutter_bloc` version &  accommodate the [breaking changes](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/2526) that came with flutter_bloc 7.2

Is there a way for me to automate the changes without having to go to every file manually ?

*I've heard I could automate the process via a **code mod** but I don't know what it is & how to use it..*

Could someone please explain or is there maybe a more simple way maybe by just search and replace some things ?

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no auto-migration.
but I have little project using:

- `flutter_bloc ^8.0.1`
- `hydrated_bloc: ^8.0.0`

here is the [link](https://github.com/Abduboriy3444/learn_bloc)

it might help you or for others

Comment: ok thanks a lot I'll take a look : )